# Adding php results to end of URL

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to get the `event id` from the example below into the *header URL* at the end of template `test.html`. Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
header("Location: templatetest.html?.$row['event_id']."); 

mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die(mysql_error());


$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM events a INNER JOIN (SELECT id_user, MAX(event_id) as maxID FROM events GROUP BY id_user) b ON a.id_user = b.id_user AND a.event_id = b.maxID WHERE a.id_user = '$test'")
or die(mysql_error()); 


// store the record of the "example" table into $row
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
};    
?>
```

Thank You.

Comment: where is example mate ???

Comment: Sorry I was entering it on my phone and the code indenting didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't eat your hamburger before you order it, pay for it and receive it. Same thing in programming. Move your `header` after the `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)`. Just make sure you don't print anything in the meantime.

Comment: and fix the syntax error to `header("Location: templatetest.html?".$row['event_id']);`

Comment: This answer helps half the problem. How do I define the parameter to get the event id in the database to appear in the URL?

Comment: @StevenReda: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. What parameter to get the event id?

Comment: Well even after I move it to after that line I'm still not grabbing the event id so I'm still not sure what is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error:

```
header("Location: templatetest.html?.$row['event_id'].");
```

and should be:

```
header("Location: templatetest.html?".$row['event_id']);
```

although `$row` will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

At the very minimum:

```
header("Location: templatetest.html?{$row['event_id']}");
```

But you <strike>need</strike> ***might** want* a url parameter ie (?something=)